# Client without Server Response (Socket)

Tags: java, sockets

The server receives remote client commands .. commandos received are properly treated and then sent back to the client .. but the client can not read the output, nothing appears in out.println ("ServerMessage");

Customer must read the received data from the server ..

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

SERVER:

```
              String MsG2X90aXk11 = "";
        Thread.sleep(100);
        while ((MsG2X90aXk11 = ShellZ.readLine()) != null) {
            BufferedWriter writeCommand = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            String message = MsG2X90aXk11;
            writeCommand.write(message+"\n");
            writeCommand.flush();
```

CLIENT:

```
            BufferedReader in = null;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
    String m6x7NXaxn102 = null;
    while ((m6x7NXaxn102 = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(m6x7NXaxn102);
    }
```

Comment: I already tried, did not work

Comment: why are you re-initiallizing the output stream on the server in the loop again and again? and what is Shellz in the server?

Comment: The company where I work needs to send codes to the central computer to monitor network traffic constantly.
SheelZ is the name of the variable BufferedReader, that takes output of remote commands

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the `line` variable. While your variable that reads each line from the input stream is `m6x7NXaxn102`

Change:

```
System.out.println(line);
```

To:

```
System.out.println(m6x7NXaxn102);
```

**Or**:

Change:

```
while((m6x7NXaxn102 = in.readLine()) != null)
```

To:

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Hope this helps. :)